# Google DiagFlow adjust chatbot Height and Width in React. Shadow Root issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, shadow-dom, diagflow

I'm trying to integrate the Google DiagFLow Chatbot in one of my projects and I came across this annoying issue where the DiagFlow chatbot isn't really responsive.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip6dG.jpg

As you can see in the above image.

Usually, i should have been able to override the css class "chat-wrapper" normally in my global.css and that should have fixed the issue. But i noticed that the chatbot element is inside two hierarchies of a "shadow root" element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dtBS.png

Now, I saw a few stackoverflow blogs but all of them suggest to manually update the dom using javascript but that's not something that is advised in React. I shouldn't have to update the dom manually just to make this work and I believe there must be a better way to do this. Any idea?

Thanks in Advance!

I haven't tried anything as I was unable to find anything React specific.

Comment: After years, and years, and years, [React still is only 71% compatible](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/) with the Custom Elements **standard**; so yes, you can safely update the DOM yourself.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, instead add the code as text.